# Can I create permalinks like this: /%post_type%/%postname%/

Tags: permalinks, custom-post-types

I've been learning about custom post types from Morten Rand-Hendriksen's great tutorial on making a WordPress portfolio theme on lynda.com.  He demos how to set up a custom taxonomy for "recipes" and create links like domain.com/?recipes=post-title.  I think this is really cool because you get a post-title with the contextual clue of "recipes" without being stuck with a bunch of nested hierarchical subdirectory archives that may be boring to look at and contain repetitious content.

For a large, multifaceted domain, I think it would be neat if there is a way to make a site behave as it has a permalink structure like this:
domain.com/%post_type%/%postname%/ for posts and custom post types, while staying with domain.com/page-name for pages.

I'm thinking of domain.com/blog/post-name for anything in the blog, though domain.com/?blog=post-title would still work.

What do you think, and what is the most practical way to go about this?

Comment: I am brand new here. Should I delete and re-post there?  My first choice would be to avoid a plugin, since I'm mucking around in there trying to learn the code anyway.

Comment: I have flagged it to be migrated, but you would have to wait for moderator to pay attention. I would repost at the wordpress site and if this one gets migrated delete it. People get cranky if they think it's a double post. If that happens just explain politely why you have two similar posts.

Comment: I'd already shared this link via FaceBook. If migration comes w/ a redirect on this link (?), I can wait.  Thanks much!

Comment: Yes, a migrated question will be automatically redirected

Answer (score 1):

When you're [registering a custom post type in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), one of the arguments is 'rewrite', which allows you to set up a slug for your custom post type. In your example above, you would set the rewrite argument to `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'recipes')` to create a URL structure like http://example.com/recipes/general-tsos-chicken

You can also add custom post types with a plugin like [Custom Post Types UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). That plugin has a field in the advanced options for adding a rewrite slug.

Comment: last night I looked over the code from Morten Rand-Hendriksen's tutorial and found (d'oh!) `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'recipes')` and got new custom post types running with the slugs I want.  I haven't found all the labels and whatnot yet, but I will.